# how to hide parent property from child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

How can I hide the parent class property in child class.

Where parent class has a property called "Parent", where I don't want to use that in child class. How can I remove or hide that.

Comment: You are asking about three completely different languages - which one are you actually using?

Comment: Just had a second look at the tags (I assumed at first you meant members), but C++ (and I assume Java) don't have properties.

Comment: @Yacoby: Yes, Java also does not.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Since he had it tagged [`c#`], [`c++`] and [`java`] but only one of them has properties, I am assuming he is asking about C#.

Comment: Are you talking about a parent-child relationship as in inheritance or parent-child as in containership?

Comment: I assumed he was using the term "property" in its most general sense.

Comment: You have asked 61 questions and have only accepted answers on 25% of them.

Answer (score 10):

So it sounds like you are asking the following. You have

```
class Parent {
    public SomeType ParentProperty { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent { }
```

and you want to hide `SomeProperty` from being visible in instances of `Child`.

Do not do this! Do not hide properties from the base class that are visible. First, it's easy to get around:

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.ParentProperty; // oops!
```

Second, it's a huge violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, the principle says that anything that you know to be true about all instances of `Parent` should also be true about all instances of `Child`. Here, we know that all instances of `Parent` have a visible property called `ParentProperty` of type `SomeType`. Therefore, the same should (moral should) be true of all instances of `Child`.

Can you tell us why you want to do this and maybe we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Note different casing is recommended for private members.

Comment: but it was public in parent class

Comment: @santose: Can you clarify if you're talking about nested classes or derived classes?

Comment: Yes, this is a current answer. If you need to hide one or more property of a base class, use Proxy Design Pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/proxy-design-pattern  and only reveal the property you want through the proxy class.

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

You have a design issue if you need this. The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) tells you that your `Child` class should be substitutable for a `Parent` class. That means that all code which uses a `Parent` class should be able to use your `Child` class instead. This is not the case if you would remove a property. You couldn't replace a Parent with a Child wherever that particular property is used.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the obvious question/answer is, maybe you should just make the property private.
(unless of course you have no access to the source to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help, you can shadow the property and set it readonly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you derived class when you say child class there's luckily no way to make it go a way. To why that would be bad tale a look at this code:

base myObj = objectFactory.Create();
myObj.theMethodHiddenAway();

the factory Can return any object of type base including all classes that derive from base. The compiler needs to decide what version of theMethodHiddenAway to call compile time (overload resulution) and since it does not no the concrete type compile time, if it was possible to make a method go away by inheritance the compiler wouldn't know if theMethodHiddenAway even existed.

I'd suggest you look at your design since what you're asking smells like one of two design flaws. Either the method does not belong there in the first place or you derived class shouldnt inherit from the base class

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A child class reference will always be implicitly convertable to a parent class reference, so you can't prevent the property from being used wihtout removing it from the parent class.