# C# different Attributes for a class and the method inside it

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a class and a method inside it. I want to use two different attributes.

```
[TokenValidate]
public class Auth
{
      [NoTokenValidate]
      Public void methodname()
      {
      }
}
```

I want that to disallow one particular method to use the parent class attribute. Is it possible?

Comment: The class is accessed first before the method. So no it is not possible.

Comment: I'd suggest reading Jason's answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162369/how-to-hide-parent-property-from-child-class). It has more to do with derived classes instead of simply methods inside of classes, but it may still be helpful to you.

Comment: As a principle, of course you can - for example, a MVC controller may be decorated with the [`[Authorize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute, but _"Within a controller that is marked with the AuthorizeAttribute attribute, you can use the AllowAnonymousAttribute attribute to specify that a particular action method is not restricted to only authorized users"_ Whether it will work for you or not though depends on how the attributes are used, as the code will need to check for this situation.