# How to remove in a child class a method inherited from a parent class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, methods, encapsulation

I have `ChildClassA`, `ChildClassB` and `ChildClassC`.

They all inherit from `ParentClass`.

How can I declare an already implemented `method` for `A` and `B`, but which is not needed in `C`?

1. Implementation in `ParentClass` doesnt make sense, since I only need it in `A` and `B`.
2. C# does not support multiple inheritance (if this would even be my best option).
3. An interface is not helping me because I cannot implement a method there.

Comment: 3d point (about interfaces) is actually not true since [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods). Though personally I prefer not to use them due to some issues/not very clear behaviour ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62334232/2501279) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295242/unexpected-behavior-of-a-c-sharp-8-0-default-interface-member)).

Comment: What do you mean `How can I add an already implemented method for A and B, but not for C?` Already implemented where? In `ParentClass`?

Comment: `How can I add an already implemented method for A and B, but which is not needed in C?` Add a ICommonToAB interface and have A and B implement it. Both of their implementations will be one line long - calling your existing logic (in class D).

Comment: I did not phrase that very well: What I mean is that the method is already defined. It does not need any change to be used on both A and B. But it would not work on C and I dont need it on C

Comment: Composition: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0OGIH5

Comment: But the logic in class `D`. A and B both have an instance of `D` internally where they call the shared logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide (remove) a base class's methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125746/) and [Can publicly inherited methods be hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106383/) and [How to hide all overrides off parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062165/) and [how to hide parent property from child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162369/) and [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/) and [Method Hiding in C#](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/function-hiding-csharp/)

Comment: My problem: I have a method which does something but is only needed in Class A and B and not C. So I dont want to inherit that method with the ParentClass. But I do not want to add it to A and B and have to change the method in A and B if I need to, since if the method changes, it will change the same way for A and B

Comment: Did you have a look into the fiddle? It's exactly what you describe in your last comment and what mjwills is trying to explain to you.

Comment: yeah its hard to write and read at the same time :-) the fiddle is exactly what i am trying to accomplish. thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a form of Composition:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new ChildA();
        a.SomeMethod();
        
        var b = new ChildB();
        b.SomeMethod();
        
        var c = new ChildC();
        // c.SomeMethod(); Doesn't have SomeMethod
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
}

public class ChildA : ParentClass, IHavingSomeMethod
{
   private readonly IHavingSomeMethod _sms;
   
   public ChildA()
   {
       _sms = new HavingSomeMethodService(); // Have it injected instead!
   }
   
   public void SomeMethod() => _sms.SomeMethod();
}

public class ChildB : ParentClass, IHavingSomeMethod
{
   private readonly IHavingSomeMethod _sms;
   
   public ChildB()
   {
       _sms = new HavingSomeMethodService(); // Have it injected instead!
   }
   
   public void SomeMethod() => _sms.SomeMethod();
}

public class ChildC : ParentClass
{
}

public interface IHavingSomeMethod
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class HavingSomeMethodService: IHavingSomeMethod
{
   public void SomeMethod()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod");
   }
}
```

[Try it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQMrGu)

Answer (score -1):

`ParentClass` inherits to

- `CommonClass`
- and `ChildClassC`

`CommonClass` inherits to

- `ChildClassA`
- and `ChildClassB`

`CommonClass` defines the `method`